# SwiftUI + MVVM + DI

Tags: dependency-injection, swiftui

I've spent a while researching this and found lots of examples of SwiftUI, MVVM and DI separately but none combined, so I'm assuming I've misunderstood something.

I have a new SwiftUI app and aiming to use the above.

I have the following

A DependencyContainer

```
protocol ViewControllerFactory {
    func makeFirstViewController() -> First_ViewModel
    func makeSecondViewController() -> Second_ViewModel
}

class DependencyContainer : ObservableObject {
    let database = AppDatabase()
}

extension DependencyContainer: ViewControllerFactory {
    func makeFirstViewController() -> First_ViewModel {
        return First_ViewModel(appDatabase: database)
    }

    func makeSecondViewController() -> Second_ViewModel {
        return Second_ViewModel()
    }
}
```

In my app entry point I have:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
            
        let container = DependencyContainer()
    
        WindowGroup {
            First_View()
            .environment(\.container, container)
        }
    }
}

private struct Container: EnvironmentKey {
  static let defaultValue = DependencyContainer()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
   var container: DependencyContainer {
      get { self[Container.self] }
      set { self[Container.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Now I run into problems
How do I use the container in the views?

```
struct First_View: View{
    @Environment(\.container) var container
    @ObservedObject private var firstViewModel : First_ViewModel

    init(){
        _firstViewModel = container.makeFirstViewController()
    }
```

Gives error

"Cannot assign value of type 'First_ViewModel' to type 'ObservedObject<First_ViewModel>'"

If I inject the container like below,

```
struct First_View: View {    
    @ObservedObject private var firstViewModel : First_ViewModel
    
    init (container : DependencyContainer){
        _firstViewModel = container.makeFirstViewController()
```

It works but not how I thought it should work

Answer (score 1):

The `@Environment()` property wrapper type relies on a defined set of key names. You can create your own ([this blog post from Use Your Loaf is a good description of how to do this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swiftui-custom-environment-values/)). This is designed for value types, though.

However, as you’ve already declared `DependencyContainer` as an `ObservableObject` you can use the `@EnvironmentObject` property wrapper:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
  @StateObject var container = DependencyContainer()

  var body: some View {
    WindowGroup {
      First_View()
        .environmentObject(container)
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in any child view where you need access, you use the `@EnvironmentObject` wrapper in your declaration. Note that you have to include the class type; you can have multiple environment objects defined, but a maximum of one of each class.

```swift
struct First_View: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var container: DependencyContainer
  // ...
}
```

Note also that `@EnvironmentObject` assumes that it will be able to find an instance of `DependencyContainer` - if it can’t find one, it will crash. When you’re defining one at the app level that shouldn’t be a problem. However, in your SwiftUI previews you will need to specify a suitable instance or the preview subsystem may crash.

So if you had a static method that prepared a preview-suitable version of your dependencies, you could write:

```swift
struct First_View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    First_View()
      .environmentObject(DependencyContainer.previewInstance)
  }
}
```